# Another weak form of the ABC conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

First I will explain why a weaker form is needed. And then I formulate the conjecture (more precisely, the formulation will be clear).

It is related to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/triangular-factorials and several Mathoverflow questions from the comments to that question. A number $m$ is called a triangular factorial if $m=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=k !$ for some $n,k$. It is an open problem  whether the set of triangle factorials is finite. Moreover the only known such numbers are $1, 6, 120$.

But (somewhat surprisingly for me) it can be  shown that the ABC conjecture implies that there are only finitely many triangular factorials. Indeed, suppose that for arbitrary large $k,m$ we have $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=k!$. Then $n+1=\frac {2k!}{n}$. Let $a=n, b=1, c= \frac {2k!}{n}$. Then by the ABC conjecture $\frac {2k!}{n}<rad(2k!)^2$ where $rad(x)$ is the product of primes dividing $x$. Note that $n\sim \sqrt{2k!}$ and $rad(2k!)=rad(k!)$ is the product of all primes $\le k$ which, by Erdos theorem $\sim e^{k}$. Thus we have $\sqrt{2k!}< e^{2k}$ which is impossible for big enough $k$. Recall that $2k!\sim 2\sqrt{2\pi k}\, e^{k\log k-k}$.

**Question:** In the proof above what seems to be a very weak version of the ABC conjecture is used (instead of $rad(abc)^{1+\epsilon}$ one can take a much bigger function in $rad(abc)$). Perhaps that version can be proved easier than the original ABC conjecture?

**Edit:** It is easy to see that in the version of ABC conjecture used here, $b=1$. Perhaps that makes the conjecture easier? So we can formulate

**A conjecture** For every constant $d<\frac 12$ there are only finite number of natural $a$ such that $$a>rad(a(a+1))^{d\log\log a}.$$
Note that the exponent in the right hand side may have to be a little different.

Comment: Best known result (Stewart, Yu) is $c < exp(O(rad(abc)^{(1/3+\epsilon)}))$ probably not enough for your application.

Comment: Yes it is not enough. But I guess you classify  Mochizuki's proof as unknown?

Comment: Yes, I do. Also, I need to write ten characters.

Comment: I thought there is a dichotomy: a written proof can be either correct or not correct. It seems that there exists the third option. It is not related to the question, though.

Comment: An unfortunate situation, but this is not the place to have this discussion.

Comment: The product of the primes up to $k$ is asymptotically $e^k$, not $e^{2k}$, and I think this is a simple consequence of the Prime Number Theorem and known before Erdos came along.

Comment: So he left out two words: which, by Erdos theorem **has square** $\sim e^{2k}.$

Comment: @Gerry  Myerson: I saw this misprint, did not fix it till now because the proof does not change.  If you know who proved it, replace Erdos by that name.  I guess that Chebyshev theorem gives $4^n$ instead of $e^n$ which would still be enough.

Comment: Note that one can rewrite this as $a^{\log \log a} > rad(a(a+1))^{\log a}$, so $(\log a)^{\log a} > rad(a(a+1))^{\log a}$, so $\log a > rad(a(a+1))$.

Comment: Your conjecture simply means that rad$(a(a+1))$ being bounded has finitely many solutions.  This is true by the finiteness of solutions to the $S$-unit equation.  But this doesn't help with the question you started with -- your reformulated conjecture is not strong enough for that application.

Comment: @Lucia: You are right. I missed one $\log$. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For $a> e$, we have $\log \log a > 0$ and hence $x^{\log \log a}$ is an increasing function, so
 $$a>\mathrm{rad}(a(a+1))^{\frac {\log a}{\log\log a}}$$

then implies that $a^{\log \log a} > \mathrm{rad}(a(a+1))^{\log a}$. Note that $a^{\log \log a} = (e^{\log a})^{\log \log a} = (e^{\log \log a})^{\log a} = (\log a)^{\log a}$.

So we have $(\log a)^{\log a} > \mathrm{rad}(a(a+1))^{\log a}$, 
so $(\log a) > \mathrm{rad}(a(a+1))$, so with $b=1$ and $c=a+1$ we have $$c > a > \exp(\mathrm{rad}(abc))$$

but for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $K$ such that $c < \exp(K\,\mathrm{rad}(abc)^{\frac13+\varepsilon})$ (Stewart & Yu 2001) , which gives a contradiction for sufficiently large $\mathrm{rad}(abc)$. So we can just  show that for every constant $L$, we have that $L > \mathrm{rad}(abc) = \mathrm{rad}(a(a+1))$ for only finitely many $a$.

This again follows form this result by Stewart & Yu (2001). If there were an infinitude of $a$ such that $L >  \mathrm{rad}(a(a+1))$, since every such triple has a different value of $c$, there are arbitrarily large values of $c$ such that $L >  \mathrm{rad}(abc)$, so $c < \exp(K\,\mathrm{rad}(abc)^{\frac13+\varepsilon})  < \exp(K\cdot L^{\frac13+\varepsilon})$, for arbitrarily large values of $c$, but the last is a constant, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It does resolve the wrong A conjecture.  The conjecture has been improved.